# How to answer this?

Tags: math, probability

Two persons are studying for a test.

X’s chances of getting a “B” are 80%. Y’s chances of getting a “B” are 90%.

The probability of at least one of them getting a “B” is 91%.

a. What is the probability that only X gets a “B”?

b. What is the probability that only Y gets a “B”?

c. What is the probability that both won’t get a “B”?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like your home work... I will give you some hints so you can get started.

```
Note: if probability of x getting a = some number c
then probability of x not getting a = 1-c

a. = (probability of x getting b)*(probability of y not getting b)
b. = (probability of y getting b)*(probability of x not getting b)
c. = you can figure it out ;)
```